# How can I create files with increasing numbers in their names every time a script is run?

Tags: bash

I need to create a file that the name increments every time it runs

```
sh SyslogClient.sh > syslogExport.log
```

next time the file would be `syslogExport1.log`, `syslogExport2.log` etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: `var=0; bash SyslogClient.sh > syslogExport$(( var++ )).log`

Comment: It does create the file with syslogexport0.log but it continues to overwrite the existing file

Comment: Well, you'd have to open and rename the file from `SyslogClient.sh` if you wanted to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
sh SyslogClient.sh > syslogExport$(( $(find . \( -name . -o -prune \) -type f -name 'syslogExport*.log' | sort -V | tail -1 | tr -cd 0-9) + 1)).log
```

- `\( -name . -o -prune \)` - don't descend into sub-directories (see [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372/14784))
- `-type f` - find files only
- `sort -V` - version sort is numeric sort but handles also chars in front
- `tail -1` - get last line (max number)
- `tr -cd 0-9` - keep only digits
- `$(...)` - capture the result of the command
- `$(( ... + 1))` - add 1 to the max number

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about the numbers being sequential (i.e.: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...), but only that they are increasing, you could use the `date` command:

```
SyslogClient.sh > syslogExport$(date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S").log
```

This will produce files like syslogExport200306155325.log, syslogExport200306155700.log, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can add these lines to the start of your script SyslogClient.sh:

```
# if logfile exists
if [ -f syslogExport.log ]
then
# count number of logfiles
count=`ls syslogExport*.log | wc -w`
# rename syslogExport.log file
mv syslogExport.log syslogExport${count}.log
fi
```

This will keep the current log in syslogExport.log and save the previous logs in syslogExport1.log, syslogExport2.log etc

Hope this helps

Comment: if someone deletes one of the log files from the middle of the sequence, this would overwrite existing files.